# Как формируется имя при комите в git если указать другие данные и насколько это безопасно?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

Как формируется имя при комите в git если указать другие данные и насколько это безопасно?

Если указываю в конфиге в vs code такие данные, то комит проходим с именем test

```
git config --global user.name "test" 
git config --global user.email "test@rambler.ru"
```

Если указываю в кофиге с такими данными то комит проходит с именем test2

```
git config --global user.name "test2" 
git config --global user.email "test2@rambler.ru"
```

если я укажу имя и эмейл другого пользователя в git и с делаю пул он получит доступ к моим кодам? не пойму, как работает система безопасности git?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете указать любое имя и любой email, и это не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к безопасности или небезопасности. Это чисто декоративная функция, которая не влияет ни на что.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: `user.name` `user.email` используются для указания авторства коммита. Причем их можно указывать произвольно. Для верификации аутентичности указанного авторства коммита есть механизм снабжения их цифровой подписью. Однако ничего в гит не контролирует "доступ к моим кодам". Это все реализуется механизмами на стороне сервера.

Comment: не совсем поняла если укажу имя и эмейл другого человека и отправлю комит у того человека чьё имя и эмейл я указала будет доступ к мои кодам или нет?

Comment: так понимаю, что user.name user.email я могу указать любые, даже если будет имя и эмейл другого пользователя у него доступа к кодам всё равно не будет?

Comment: На гитхабе авторство коммитов для разграничения доступа не используется.

Comment: понимаю так можно писать любое имя и эмейл и даже если данные сойдутся с другим аккаунтом, у другого аккаунта доступа не будет?

Comment: Будет у него доступ или нет опеределяется не тем, что указано в коммите, а тем есть ли у учетной записи пользователя доступ к вашему репозиторию.

Comment: поняла если не добавила пользователя в вкладке колоборация значит доступа не будет